# Neo4j graph performance: should I cache slow queries in a separate database?

Tags: database, api-design, graph, graph-traversal, graph-databases

**Setup/Intro**

I have 10k+ nodes in my Neo4j graph in which I need to display a sub-graph (100-500 nodes) between 2 start/end nodes on the frontend app along with info about the critical path and all dependencies (upstream/downstream paths from/to start/end) of each node.

I have a list of all possible start/end nodes and it's tiny (~10 pairs).

The start and end nodes are the params of the request.

The response I have sent from middleware API to UI now is something like this:

```
Nodes: [
{
  Id: 4,
  downstreamIds: [5,6,7], //all nodes on the paths leading to end node
  upstreamIds: [1,2,3], //all nodes on the paths coming from start node
  ...
},
...
]
```

**Problem**

The issue is that for each node I have 2 separate queries to get both the downstream and upstream lists like this one:

```
MATCH path = (o:Operation)-[DEPENDS_ON*]->(start:Operation ) WHERE id(o) = $operationId RETURN path
```

...so for n nodes I have 1 query for the nodes + 2n queries for downstream+upstream + 1 query for some aggregated stats.

It takes 502 queries to fetch a start/end sub-graph that has 500 nodes in it.

The aggregated stats query is one traversal and it is fast not an issue.

However overall this request can take up 2 minutes in worst case scenario i.e: each node has all other nodes as downstream and upstream dependencies.

**Possible solutions**

1. Return a list of all relationships which is 2n² edges (500 * 500 * 2 for worst case) and calculate the downstream/upstream list in UI using Javascript. I'm not really sure how to do that with Cypher.
   Also storing 500,000 objects and filtering them in UI doesn't sound right.
2. Pre-process the queries for downstream/upstream for each node and cache them in a separate fast key-value store. I'm thinking nosql mongoDB.
   So I request for the nodes from graph then get the dependencies from the key-value store with 1 extra query (much faster/no graph traversal)

Which is better? Any other solutions?

Comment: Where does operationId come from, could you query for all IDs in a single query, then split them back out on the client side?

Comment: operationId is the id of the node I want to get the relationships for. This query runs once for each node. I need to get this info for each node separately.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little more than half a year old, but thought I might share an answer just in case. I don't have a specific answer for this problem, but I can share my use case and personal solution for inspiration.

My use case for needing subgraphs: I have a chain of processes that produce output files as inputs to other processes, e.g. (Process_1)-[:OUTPUTS]->(File)-[:INPUTS]->(Process_2). I wanted to find all downstream processes given any starting one. I use the [apoc library subgraphNodes](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/expand-subgraph-nodes/) function to define my path and give me only the nodes.

```
match(n:Process {id:$id})
call apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {
  relationshipFilter:'OUTPUTS,INPUTS',
  labelFilter:'>Process'
})
yield node
return node
```

In my case I didn't need to provide an ending node since I wanted the whole subgraph. But perhaps you could use the [terminatorNodes](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/expand-subgraph-nodes/#expand-subgraph-nodes-examples-end-nodes-terminator-nodes) parameter for that.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I ended up caching the downstream Ids in a property.  This solution suited my usecase and enhanced the performance dramatically.